# Getting compile error on .ListItems in VB6

Tags: vb6

I'm getting an error compiling("Method or data member not found") a VB6 project. It fails on any line using .ListItems

I've commented a couple out and it gets to the next. I believe I'm missing a reference or dependency but unsure which and how to add it.

While looking online I saw suggestions of "comctl32.ocx", downloaded it, tried to register it using Regsvr32.

Have tried in project>References and adding it, but get the error "Can't remove control or reference; in use" but after that error twice it shows in the list of references and ticked as "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 5.0 (SP2)" but after pressing ok it gives "Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library". But I can't see that in the references list anywhere else

Example lines that fail:

```
lstAlertsList.ListItems.Clear

lstAlertsList.ListItems.Add
```

Comment: Which control are you using when getting this error?

Comment: I assume that's a treeview. What does Project > Components (Ctrl-T) show if you check Selected Items Only? - If you're using VB6, you would usually be using Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 and assuming you have SP6 installed that should be followed by "(SP6)". That should reference MSCOMCTL.OCX.

Comment: Oops. That should read "Listview" not "Treeview", but both are included in the same component and OCX file.

Comment: Tried that, ticking "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP4)" which shows location as "C:\WINDOWS\SysWow64\mscomctl.ocx" but I get the error: Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library

It does have common controls-2 5.0 (SP2) and Common Controls-3 6.0 (SP5) ticked, do I need to untick these first? or would the conflict be caused by something else?

When I select the control it shows as a PictureBox, but it's displaying info in a grid layout so I'm kind of a bit confused on that

Comment: VB will default to treating controls as PictureBox when it can't figure out what they really are.

Comment: Like the first comment asks, what is the type of `lstAlertsList`?

Comment: Looking in Object browser it shows "WithEvents lstAlertsList As Listbox" and below that shows "Member of Unknown1. Form"

When I click on Listbox and goes to the VB library in object browser with Listbox highlighted

I tried removing it and creating a new listbox on the form with the same name but has the same issue

I also found this line for the click event:
`Private Sub lstAlertsList_ItemClick(ByVal Item As ComctlLib.ListItem)`
Could it be the ComctlLib is missing?

Comment: @AndyBruce One of your issues is that a Listbox does not have a `ListItems` property.